# Problems with Raspberry Pi Resolution

Tags: screen, config.txt

I recently purchased a Raspberry Pi and I hooked it up to my 22" Acer monitor. The monitor has a resolution of 1680x960. I tried several resolutions in the config.txt and some of them make the resolution default to the htmi_safe=1 resolution. Others are too fuzzy. I looked through the wiki for the resolution and I can't find mine. Can someone suggest me a proper resolution for my RPi.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please state what settings you tried in your `config.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. So my settings are now hdmi_group = 1 and mode=0x3a. My Pi also autodetects my monitor now and adjusts accordingly. I had to fiddle around with the resolution frequency but I managed to fix that up. Thanks guys :)